# How to filter an array of objects based on two filters?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have this array of objects:

```
const myArr = [{
  name: 'A',
  type: 1,
  subtype: 1
},
{
  name: 'B',
  type: 1,
  subtype: 2
},
{
  name: 'C',
  type: 2,
  subtype: 3
},
{
  name: 'D',
  type: 3,
  subtype: 1,
}];
```

Then I have two variables, each one with an ID. These are the `typeId` and `subtypeId`. These can be either a numeric value that matches the types and subtypes on the array above, or can be `-1` which means "All".

So, I'll show some cases and what the filters should return:

```
type: 1 | subtype: 1 --> A
type: -1 | subtype: -1 --> ABCD
type: 1 | subtype: -1 --> AB
type: 2 | subtype: 3 --> C
type: 2 | subtype: 2 --> nothing
type: 3 | subtype: 1 --> D
```

You get the point.

```
const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
    const { typeId, subtypeId } = getCurrentFilterIds();

    if(typeId === -1) return true;
    if(typeId !== -1){
      if(subtypeId === -1) return item.type === typeId;
      if(subtypeId !== -1) return item.type === typeId && item.subtype === subtypeId;
    }
  });
```

I came up with this function but maybe there's a better way?

Comment: You should move the call of `getCurrentFilterIds()` out of the `Array.filter` call, otherwise it is going to be called for each item in the data array.

Comment: What about the case when `typeId` is `-1` but `subtypeId` is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you do not want to call getCurrentFilterIds() for each item in the list. So this should be moved outside the filter function.

Your ifs are a bit redundant and unnecessary. You could use if-else instead. But in this case, since you are returning a value if the first statement is true, an else statement is not needed as well. So you can simply do:

```
const { typeId, subtypeId } = getCurrentFilterIds();
const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
    if (typeId === -1) return true;
    if (subtypeId === -1) return item.type === typeId;
    return item.type === typeId && item.subtype === subtypeId;
});
```

You could even go a step further and return the result in a single line and get rid of all ifs.

```
const { typeId, subtypeId } = getCurrentFilterIds();
const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
    return (typeId === -1) || ((item.type === typeId) && (subtypeId === -1 || item.subtype === subtypeId));
});
```

Comment: the second option is far less readable IMO

Answer (score 0):

You could take the conditions directly as expression instead of using `if` statements.

```js
const
    filter = (array, typeId, subtypeId) => array.filter(o =>
        typeId === -1 ||
        o.type === typeId && (subtypeId === -1 || o.subtype === subtypeId)
    ),
    data = [{ name: 'A', type: 1, subtype: 1 }, { name: 'B', type: 1, subtype: 2 }, { name: 'C', type: 2, subtype: 3 }, { name: 'D', type: 3, subtype: 1 }];



console.log(filter(data, 1, 1));   // A
console.log(filter(data, -1, -1)); // A B C D
console.log(filter(data, 1, -1));  // A B
console.log(filter(data, 2, 3));   // C
console.log(filter(data, 2, 2));   // []
console.log(filter(data, 3, 1));   // D
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The check on the property is the same wether it is on `type` or `subtype` that is for a given *x*:

- if *x* is -1 then any property value is fine
- Otherwise the property value must be equal to *x*

So we can formalise this with:

```js
const propCheck = (k, x) => o => x === -1 ? true : o[k] === x;
//                 ^  ^     ^  
//                 1  2     3

// 1: property name e.g. 'type' or 'subtype'
// 2: x e.g. -1 or 2
// 3: the object to read the property from
```

We can write an `and` function that takes two functions then a value, applies both functions to it and returns true if both did:

```js
const and = (f, g) => x => f(x) && g(x);
```

Get your `typeId` and `subtypeId` and pass them to the corresponding `propCheck` calls. e.g.

```js
myArr.filter(and(propCheck('type', 2), propCheck('subtype', 3)));
//=> [{name: "C", type: 2, subtype: 3}]

myArr.filter(and(propCheck('type', 2), propCheck('subtype', 2)));
//=> []

myArr.filter(and(propCheck('type', 1), propCheck('subtype', -1)));
//=> [ {name: "A", type: 1, subtype: 1}
//=> , {name: "B", type: 1, subtype: 2}]
```